# Access - query to pull the most recent entry for each unique opportunity

Tags: sql, ms-access

From a table called `tblNotes`, I need to get the most recent `notedata` for each `opportunityid`.

Here is what the data looks like in `tblNotes`.

[image]

Here is what I'd like the data to look like:

[image]

I don't know much about SQL, but I have figured out I need an inner query.  The reading I've done says Access stored `notesdate` as a date and time code.

Here is the code I've cobbled together

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tblNotes AS t1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT opportunityid, notesdata, MAX(notesdate) AS MaxDate 
     FROM tblnotes GROUP BY opportunityid, notesdata)  
    AS t2 ON (t1.opportunityid=t2.opportunityid) AND  (t1.notesdate=t2.MaxDate);
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

As you can see...not even close.  I am thinking the basic structure is hiding in there somewhere...maybe.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select n.*
from tblNotes as n
where n.notesId = (select top 1 n2.notesId
                   from tblNotes as n2
                   where n2.opportunityId = n.opportunityId
                   order by n2.notesDate desc, n2.notesId desc
                  );
```

Assuming that `notesid` is a primary key, this returns one row per `opportunityId`, even if there are multiple notes on the most recent date.  If you want *all* notes on the most recent date, then use:

```
select n.*
from tblNotes as n
where n.notesDate = (select max(t2.notesDate)
                     from tblNotes as n2
                     where n2.opportunityId = n.opportunityId
                    );
```

Comment: NotesID is a PK.  Upon further review the first block of code almost did what I needed.  Once I removed the parenthesis around the 1, the query returned on result per `opportunityid` where with a related `notesid`.  I need to return a blank entry for any `opportunityid` where there isn't a corresponding 'notesid`.  Any thoughts?  I will post a new question if it more appropriate to do so.  Thanks.

Comment: Reverted back to this being the correct solution since it did indeed answer the question I posed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clean: create an in-line search table with oppty-id and max notes-date per oppty-id, from the input, and inner join that table back to the input on both the smaller table's columns:

```
DROP TABLE input;                                                                  
CREATE TABLE 
input(notesid,opportunityid,notesdate,notesuser,notesdata) AS 
          SELECT  5,0,DATE '2020-07-14',3,'kkk'
UNION ALL SELECT  3,1,DATE '2020-07-14',2,'another test to run'
UNION ALL SELECT  1,1,DATE '2020-07-14',2,'This is just a test. Next action is..'
UNION ALL SELECT  9,1,DATE '2020-07-27',4,'test'
UNION ALL SELECT 12,1,DATE '2020-07-28',1,'another day in paradise'
UNION ALL SELECT 13,1,DATE '2020-08-14',1,'another test .. maybe this time'
UNION ALL SELECT  2,6,DATE '2020-07-14',3,'another test to see how it works'
;

SELECT
  i.*
FROM input i
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    opportunityid
  , MAX(notesdate) AS notesdate
  FROM input
  GROUP BY opportunityid
) m
  ON m.opportunityid=i.opportunityid
 AND m.notesdate    =i.notesdate
-- out  notesid | opportunityid | notesdate  | notesuser |            notesdata            
-- out ---------+---------------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------
-- out        2 |             6 | 2020-07-14 |         3 | another test to see how it works
-- out        5 |             0 | 2020-07-14 |         3 | kkk
-- out       13 |             1 | 2020-08-14 |         1 | another test .. maybe this time
```